# Remove all duplicates based on different columns and rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have this condition:

```
    ID  N1      N2
    1   6387    6187 
    2   6290    6386 
    3   6295    6295 
    4   6043    6392 
    5   6042    6043
    6   6050    6031 
    7   6050    6036 
    8   6321    6434 
    9   6440    6397
```

with duplicates in different columns and rows, and I would like to remove ALL duplicates in N1 and N2, like this:

```
ID  N1      N2
1   6387    6187 
2   6290    6386 
8   6321    6434 
9   6440    6397
```

I tried these codes:

```
dt[(duplicated(dt[,2:3]) | duplicated(dt[,2:3], fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

and

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% distinct(N1,N2, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

But didn't work.

Comment: Why. you are removing the row `6042 6043`

Comment: Because I considered the ID, so, the ID had a replicate. Did you understand?

Comment: From the dataset, it looks like unique ID in each row

Comment: A don't want replicates into ID and among IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the contents of your data frame into a vector, then check duplicated forward or duplicated backward. Next reshape these results into the same dimensions as your data and filter to rows where the rowSum of this new `dupes` data is 0, i.e. no column is a dupe. (not clear if you want to include ID in your dupe checks, but you can change `unlist(df)` to `unlist(df[some_columns])` and it will work the same.

```
df_vec <- unlist(df)
dupes <- duplicated(df_vec) | duplicated(df_vec, fromLast = TRUE)
df[rowSums(matrix(dupes, nrow(df))) == 0,]

#   ID   N1   N2
# 1  1 6387 6187
# 2  2 6290 6386
# 8  8 6321 6434
# 9  9 6440 6397
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 pivot_longer(-c(ID, rowid)) %>%
 group_by(value) %>%
 filter(n() == 1) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 filter(n() == 2) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
 select(-rowid)

     ID    N1    N2
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1  6387  6187
2     2  6290  6386
3     8  6321  6434
4     9  6440  6397
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` solution (`data.table` is only loaded to `fread()` the data):

```
library(data.table)

my_data <- fread("
ID  N1      N2
1   6387    6187 
2   6290    6386 
3   6295    6295 
4   6043    6392 
5   6042    6043
6   6050    6031 
7   6050    6036 
8   6321    6434 
9   6440    6397
")

# duplicated entries
dup <- c(my_data$N1, my_data$N2)[duplicated(c(my_data$N1, my_data$N2))]

# keep rows that do not bear any of the duplicated entries
my_data[!(my_data$N1 %in% dup | my_data$N2 %in% dup),]

   ID   N1   N2
1:  1 6387 6187
2:  2 6290 6386
3:  8 6321 6434
4:  9 6440 6397
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own method only needed modified a little to concatenate the two columns instead of passing them as a 2x10 array.

```r
nondupes <- !duplicated(c(dt[,2], dt[,3])) & 
            !duplicated(c(dt[,2], dt[,3]), fromLast = TRUE)

dt[nondupes[1:nrow(dt)] & nondupes[nrow(dt) + 1:nrow(dt)],]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to filter using `dplyr`. Each line builds up the logic:

- Remove N1 duplicates (forward)
- Remove N2 duplicates (forward)
- Remove N1 duplicates (backwards)
- Remove N2 duplicates (backwards)
- Remove where N1 is in N2
- Remove where N2 is in N1

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!duplicated(N1),
         !duplicated(N2),
         !duplicated(N1, fromLast = TRUE),
         !duplicated(N2, fromLast = TRUE),
         !(N1 %in% N2),
         !(N2 %in% N1))
```